# How to open root@ad02e79cfb5b directory in windows terminal?

Tags: docker, root, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Linux subsystem and windows terminal. I ran image using docker (command of the form docker run -it ......  where "......" refers to further part of syntax).

After running of command finished, my current directory (which was PS C:\Users\krs>) changed to root@ad02e79cfb5b and i saw my project directory (say ProjectX) there (it was highlisghted in green) along with other directories like lib,tmp,bin (similar to linux directories in root folder).

However I don't know where root@ad02e79cfb5b:/# is present. I thought it might be root directory but when i open root directory there are folders like lib,tmp,bin but not ProjectX. I am also not able to open root@ad02e79cfb5b:/# using command cd root@ad02e79cfb5b:/#.

Where is root@ad02e79cfb5b:/# located ? How to access it again once I closed it?

Comment: When you run `docker run` with the `-it` flag it will run the container and give you a shell into it. So the `root@ad02e79cfb5b:/#` you were seeing was the prompt inside the docker container (`root` is the user, `ad02e79cfb5b` is the host name and `/` means you are in the root folder). To get back into it just `docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash` if the container is still running or run it again if it stopped.

Comment: @MatteoZanoni thanks it worked.  You might write it as answer. I will accept it. Also how to know host name ? fortunately I noted ad02e79cfb5b  but suppose I would not have noted it how did I knew this alpha-numeric sequence ?

Comment: That sounds like your Dockerfile is missing the `CMD` that specifies the default command the main container should run.  Can you provide a [mcve], including the Dockerfile and the `docker run` command you're using to start the container?

Comment: @MatteoZanoni also where to learn about docker so that I can know these things ? Most sources don't provide these details.

Comment: As a note if you give the `--name name1` flag then you can run all docker commands passing the container name instead of container id (as it is easier to remember). E.g.: `docker exec -it name1 /bin/bash`

Comment: @DavidMaze I ran following : docker run -it --name name1--mount type=bind,source=C:\Users\krs\Downloads\ProjectX,dst=somewebsite.com:someword  . Sorry , I made this comment earlier but tagged Matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `docker run` with the `-it` flag it will run the container and give you a shell into it.
So the `root@ad02e79cfb5b:/#` you were seeing was the prompt inside the docker container (`root` is the user, `ad02e79cfb5b` is the host name and `/` means you are in the root folder).

To get back into it you first need to know if the container is still running. To achieve this run `docker ps -a` (not the thant the `-a` flag is important as without it you will only see running containers and not stopped ones).

If the container you ran is still running then note the id and run `docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash` to get a shell back to it.

If the container is stopped then I would suggest removing it `docker rm <container-id>` and re-running it (`docker run -it ...`).